# How to know if route exists before i do transition

Tags: ember.js

I want re-transition my application when route not found, in my application route

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(model, transition) {
    if (transition.targetName == "not-found") {
      var newPath = transition.intent.url  //do some logic
      this.transitionTo(newpath);
    }
  }
});
```

**Question** How to check if `newPath` exist before I do `this.transitionTo(newPath);`

In API I found only private `hasRoute`

**UPDATE** for better understand the problem

For example i have routes:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('login'),
  this.route('not-found', { path: '/*wildcard' });
});
```

When user request `URI` for example `en/login` ember load `not-found` route (default as Wildcard). Real path is `login`.

I want remove `en` and try to find out if `login` route exist in my application, otherwise it will be real "not-found" page

`en/login` == `login` and it's valid, will redirect to login

`en/abc` == `abc` this route does not exist, `not-found` continue execution

Comment: I assume you mean the `hasRoute` of `Ember.Router`. There's also the (also still private, but according to code comments hopefully sometime public) [routing service](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RoutingService.html) ([source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.8.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/services/routing.js)) which you can inject anywhere with `Ember.inject.service('-routing')`

Comment: Why? Ember recommends to pass route's name to transitionTo, not an url. How it is possible that route doesn't exist? Please explain what do you try to achieve.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This help me find sequence of matched routes

```
var recognizer = this.get('router.router.recognizer');
recognizer.recognize(currentPath);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Would hope for a more detailed example.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

`` getOwner(this).lookup(`route:${routeName}`); ``

from any object created from the container (route, controller, component, service) to test if `routeName` is a valid route. If it is, you'll get back a `Route` object, and if not you'll get `undefined` (so you can just check for truthiness).

Answer (score 0):

With the transition to embroider the `` getOwner(this).lookup(`route:${routeName}`) `` answer doesn't work anymore, however you can now use the [router service](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/RouterService) which is public to determine if a route exists. It doesn't look like `hasRoute` is part of the API, but we're handling this by calling `urlFor` and dealing with the exception it throws when the route doesn't exist:

```js
get hasRoute() {
  try {
    return Boolean(this.router.urlFor('dashboard'));
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}
```